# Can a 75" TV be safely mounted on two steel studs?

Tags: drywall

I hired a handyman to wall mount my 75 inch TV on the party wall of our townhouse. The wall has 2 layers of drywall (about 1.5 inch total thickness) on steel studs, and has a few inches space behind it that’s filled with insulation, followed by the drywall of the neighboring townhouse. Some spots seem to have 2 studs adjacent to each other (or wider studs). There’s also some kind of horizontal fire barrier/break in certain areas.

The handyman managed to get 2 studs, but the rest of the screws are in the drywall. The wall seems to be supporting the weight of the TV fine so far (it’s been a few weeks), but I’m wondering if this will hold up long term. Appreciate any advice from this community!

Comment: The meta discussion and pseudo-answers above can be cleaned up. I've revised the question wording for clarity. FYI, it's probably two layers of 5/8" drywall (1-1/4" total). 3/4" drywall is rare, at least in the U.S.

Comment: Mimster, please clarify what "the rest of the screws are in the drywall" means. I doubt that there are bare screws threaded into gypsum and paper.

Comment: *What does it weigh?* Diagonal size indicates very little.

Answer (score 4):

Someone told me that at his business a large TV was hung on drywall without hitting any studs. This guy expressed concern to the installer who proceeded to do chin-ups on the bracket.

Double drywall is very strong. If your installer used the correct fasteners, your TV should be secure with a very large margin.

The guy that told me this is an experienced remodeler. He thinks the [Hilti toggle bolts](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hilti-HTB-3-8-in-Dry-Wall-Metal-Anchor-Bolt-with-Slotted-Round-Head-Screw-25-Pack-2158774/308158611) hold very well in drywall. They come in four sizes: 3/16", 1/4", 3/8", 1/2".

Comment: Requests for clarification should go in a comment on the question post.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the many similar questions on this site usually involve a single layer of 1/2" drywall. This is a very different case, with more than twice that thickness and double the facing (paper) layers and screws. Virtually any modern TV could be hung well with togglers alone.